# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC Apache Cordova 4 no project files

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

I'm experiencing a very weird behavior after updating my Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC. As part of the update it updates the Apache Cordova to Update 4 and after installation all project files for the Tools of Apache Cordova project are missing.

Just for an example I created an empty project of Tools for Apache Cordova and the only folder I see is Dependencies with empty Bower and NPM folders.

The folder of the project in the file system does contain all the files. They are just not reflected by Visual Studio.

[Screenshot of new Apache Cordova project in VS2015 Update 1 RC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB4RF.png)

BTW, the same happens for my existing project.

I tried to uninstall VS2015 completely, install the regular VS2015 and then install the Update 1 on top of it again. The same result.

Has anyone experienced such a behavior? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hi @Lentyai - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft. I'd like to investigate this issue further. The first step is looking at your setup logs. Could you run http://aka.ms/vscollect and upload the logs somewhere for my team to investigate? (note: the tool will save a file called vslogs.zip and place it in your %temp% directory)

Comment: @Michael hi, thanks for your assistance! Here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxl3i80iewidvdk/vslogs.zip?dl=0) to the full thread of logs. Let me know whether it helped identify the problem. I've tried to uninstall and re-install VS2015, uninstall all Visual Studio versions I had on my machine and then re-install VS2013 with Cordova tools and then installing VS2015 again. Unfortunately, nothing helped. The outcome is the same as in the original question I posted.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have my team look at these logs. Hopefully they will help. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your logs. We're still looking over them. The steps I gave in my answer have worked for other customers, so hopefully they'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your MEF cache is corrupted and needs to be reset. To do this, delete this folder in Windows Explorer and restart VS:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

We are still not sure how to get into this state but we've had customers resolve the problem in the past by deleting this folder. Please let me know if that fixes it for you. (disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)

Comment: unfortunately this suggestion of yours didn't help. I've already saw that this approach helped some people in other cases and tried it before. I've also done it again right now and the result is the same, no project files except the Dependencies folder with empty Bower and NPM folders exactly as on the screentshot in my original post. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's too bad. This sounds like a different problem. I would like to understand what's going on. Can you contact me at mbraude@microsoft.com? I'd like to arrange a time for one of my team to contact you and debug your machine.